# Installing kubectl on 'dataflowrunner' workers

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kubectl, dataflow, google-cloud-sdk

I want to seed data in my elasticsearch cluster running on kubernetes. The data I have is on Bigquery and I want to use dataflow(python) to load the data. The python apache-beam version does not seem to have an elastic-search sink. I wrote my own elasticsearch writer in dataflow but I need to portforward my elasticsearch port from the kubernetes cluster. So i need to install google-cloud-sdk and kubectl so i can forward the port write my data and close it back afterwards. My code seems to work fine when I run the job locally but I can't seem to install google-cloud-sdk and kubectl on the workers.

My code seems to work fine when I run the job locally but I can't seem to install google-cloud-sdk and kubectl on the workers.

these are the commands that get called in the setup.py in a subprocces.Popen

```
['export', 'CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release', '-c', '-s)"'],
['echo', '"deb', 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt', '$CLOUD_SDK_REPO', 'main"', '|', 'sudo', 'tee', '-a', '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list'],
['sudo', 'rm', '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/partner.list'],
['sudo', 'apt-get', 'install', 'google-cloud-sdk', 'kubectl']
```

this is my method for port forwarding the elasticsearch service in the start_bundle

```
def _open_connection(self):
    tries = 0
    connected = False
    while tries <= 3 and not connected:
        tries += 1
        try:
            res = requests.get('http://{0}:{1}'.format(self.host, self.port))
            connected = (res.status_code == 200)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(e)
            subprocess.check_call('gcloud container clusters get-credentials {0}'.format(ES_CLUSTER_NAME), shell=True)
            try:
                subprocess.check_call('kubectl version', shell=True)
            except exception as ee:
                logging.warning(ee)
                subprocess.check_call('gcloud components install kubectl', shell=True)
            subprocess.call('kubectl port-forward elasticsearch-0 {0}:{0} & disown'.format(self.port), shell=True)
            time.sleep(3)
    return connected
```

I expect these commands (I tried variations) to install the required packages on every worker, but the installation keeps failing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by skipping port-forwarding and instead implementing an [internal load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) on my elasticsearch port. This way my dataflow workers can directly connect to the internal IP to write the data.